# Jest how to test the line which calls a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, testng

I have a command line application.
The file has several functions but how can I test the line that calls the first function.

For example

```
function child(ch) {
  console.log(ch);
}


function main(a) {
  console.log(a);
  child('1');
}

main(24);
```

How can I test here that main has been called when the file loads.

Comment: You are looking for spyOn https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: Can you test the *behaviour*, in this case that `24` then `'1'` get logged, instead?

Comment: The question is not how to test that it calls `main()`. Who cares if it calls `main()`? What if tomorrow you decide to rename `main()` to something else? What if `main()` does not do anything important for the module and there is another function that needs to be called to complete the module initialization? Identify why do you call `main()` in the first place and verify that, after the module is loaded, `main()` or whatever its name is did that thing that needs to be done, that thing that made you decide to write the `main()` function **and** call it. This is why the tests must be done first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind splitting your file in two different files:

**index.js**

```js
import main from './main.js';

main(24);
```

**main.js**

```js
function child(ch) {
  console.log(ch);
}


function main(a) {
  console.log(a);
  child('1');
}

export default main;
```

You can then mock the *main()* function from *main.js* and check that it gets called on *index.js* import:

**index.spec.js**

```js
const mockedMain = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../main.js', () => ({
  default: () => mockedMain(),
}));

describe('test that main is called on index.js import', () => {
  it('should call main', () => {
    require('../index.js');
    expect(mockedMain).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I do not know any way to do the same thing while keeping *main()* in the same file.